# pandas Categorical.add_categories() not working

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Please consider the following piece of code:

```
cat1 = pd.Categorical(list('bcbcac'), list('cb'), ordered=True)
cat1.add_categories(['a'], inplace= True)
print(cat1)
[b, c, b, c, NaN, c]
Categories (3, object): [c < b < a]
```

Here I've added the category 'a' after creating the 'cat1' categorical object. But when I printed the object, the item 'a' is not properly categorized (showing NaN). Will be really helpful if somebody can explain this behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to redeclare the data, because 'a' didn't exist as a category when cat1 was declared. Categorical has rejected 'a' and replaced it with NaN. You could fix it by replacing NaN with 'a' when the new category is added.

```
cat1.fillna('a')
```